# How to fetch latest data from an array of data saved in a JSON doc in cloudant?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, cloudant

I'm trying to connect to cloudant db and fetch docs. There is an array of a specific field (say querytime). There are multiple docs and each doc has multiple entries in querytime field, I need to fetch the latest querytime from that array.

> querytime

```
["Tue Apr 25 07:32:50 2017", "Tue Apr 25 07:33:51 2017", "Tue Apr 25 07:34:51 2017", 30 more...]

$http(req).then(function(result){
    $scope.tableData = result.data.rows;
    $scope.max = Math.max.apply(Math,$scope.tableData.map(function(doc){return doc.querytime;}));
    },
    function(){
    console.log("Failed at grabbing data");
                });
```

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="tutorialCtrl">
<p>
{{"Hello " + "you"}}
</p>
    <div ng-repeat="doc in tableData">
        {{doc.doc.querytime}}
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code would work if querytime was a numeric value. Since querytime is an array you need to get the max of each max in the array, like so:

```
$scope.max = Math.max.apply(Math,$scope.tableData.map(function(doc){
   return Math.max.apply(Math,doc.querytime);
}));
```

Note that I replaced:

```
return doc.querytime;
```

With:

```
return Math.max.apply(Math,doc.querytime)
```

That will give you the max value across all documents. If you want the max for each document you would do something like this:

Controller:

```
$scope.getMaxQuerytime() = function(doc) {
   return Math.max.apply(Math,doc.querytime);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="doc in tableData">
    {{getMaxQuerytime(doc)}}
</div>
```